# Markers as "list" in python scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, scatter

I'm trying to create a scatter plot where the markers are not all the same but 
are numbers in sequential order.

let's have, for instance, this code

```
x = numpy.random.rand(10)
y = numpy.random.rand(10)

plt.scatter(x,y)
```

this will display all equal markers on the plot.

I would like to display numbers instead of the same marker, in sequential order.

Specifically I would like to display for the points

x[0],y[0] --> number 1

x[1],y[1] --> number 2

x[2],y[2] --> number 3

and so on...

Can you help me to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
numbers = np.arange(len(x))
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.text(x[i], y[i], numbers[i])
```

[image]